# Use docker client without HyperV

Tags: windows, docker, docker-machine

My laptop came with Windows 10 Home, which does not have the HyperV feature. I would like to use `docker-machine` with the `virtualbox` driver, which should technically be possible without HyperV. But I can't install Docker in the first place because of missing HyperV. Is there a way around that?

[image]

---

**Update** I found [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/)! The documentation states that [it is a legacy solution](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/) though.

Answer (score 1):

you could install the linux subsystem on your windows machine:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

i think this will allow you to install docker, and as long as you have a bash window open, the docker engine will remain active

EDIT: Docker for Windows is now available (without HyperV), this will run in the background and would probably be better

Comment: The linux subsystem requires Windows 10 Pro+, too.

Comment: linux subsystem has docker command line. Not the deamon, though.

Comment: WSL can be enabled on Windows 10 Home! `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux`

Comment: I have been using WSL on Home without any special steps. Simply installed Ubuntu from the Windows Store.